# Observable collection Add object doesn't refresh view

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

This is my code, when i press button binded with `Clicked` property `addische` the new item is added to the ListView but I can't see it in the list.

```
public partial class GS : ContentPage
{
    private GSViewModel _viewModel;

    public GS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new GSViewModel();
    }

    private void addische(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.newItemAdded();
    }

    public class GSViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<schItem> _scheListItem;
        public ObservableCollection<schItem> Items { get { return _scheListItem; }
            private set
            {
                if (_scheListItem != value)
                {
                    _scheListItem = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public void newItemAdded()
        {
            Items.Add(new schItem
            {
                realm_id = 133,
                list_id = 33
            });
        }

        public GSViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<schItem>();
            initListView();
        }

        public void initListView()
        {
           //get data
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class schItem
    {
        public int realm_id { get; set; }
        public int list_id { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Maybe i missing something with `INotifyPropertyChanged` class.

> I'm debugging in Android Device

Comment: Need your xaml to see bindings

Comment: here http://pastebin.com/Usv8ESFZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few reasons why you may not see anything.

1. You bindings are wrong, so you will not see any text. To fix change

   ```
         <Label Text = "{Binding name}" HeightRequest="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
         <Label Text = "{Binding data, StringFormat='a {0:F0}'}" />
   ```

to

```
      <Label Text = "{Binding realm_id}" HeightRequest="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
      <Label Text = "{Binding list_id}" />
```

2. Check if "delete.png" exists in correct place and it is not "delete.jpg"
3. After that is fixed remove ListView IsEnabled="False"

[image]

Comment: 1) I'm sorry! I've removed name and data from the code to simplify;
2) delete.png exist, i see it;
3) I won't the touch listener on listview.
The problem isn't the initial view but the updated view after insert new item.

Comment: After I fixed all in the answer I can see AFTER I add an item. If you need help you can install teamviewer and we can do remote session from chat room

Comment: There is StackOverflow ;) maybe this question will be useful for other people. If you need more code ask for that, but i think it's enough. let me know about any suggestion

Comment: I don't need any more code. Fix what I told you and that will work. Good luck

Comment: Ok now it works, the problem was about `isEnabled="False"`, but i can't let the listview disabled and dynamically add items?

Comment: Yes you can add items while list is disabled. You just cannot click on them. Your problem was binding not enabled or may be button click, you didn't provide any code for that

Comment: No, if i set isEnabled="False" i can't see new items, instead if i set isEnabled="True" new item is showed

Comment: I already suggested to take a look and try to fix it for you. You didn't want to, so what else I can tell you? It works for me with disabled list view. Try to update nuget packages to latest. May be the problem is there

Comment: What did you do? That may help to other people.